# Why was Sean's father different in the portrait?

Tags: character, casting, before-i-wake

In *Before I Wake*, the Hobson family had Jessie Hobson, Mark Hobson and their dead son Sean. But in the portrait there was some other guy:

[image: Screenshot contains a man looking at a portrait with man, women in blonde hair and their son.]

But there was no mention about the previous father/husband of the family in the entire film. So who was with this guy? Was that some previous casting goof-up or something which was cut out of the film?